# php string replace array and create new nested array

Tags: php

I have an array, I can print it with

```
print_r($show_arr);
```

it gives me this output(html source)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Marvel's Daredevil.S01E01 - Into the Ring.mp4
    [1] => Marvel's Daredevil.S01E02 - Cut Man.mp4
    [2] => Marvel's Daredevil.S02E05 - Kinbaku.mp4
    [3] => Marvel's Daredevil.S02E06 - Regrets Only.mp4   
)
```

how would I go about getting the array to look like this?

```
Array
(
      Season[1] => Array
                  (
                     Array(
                          episode =>  "01 - Into the Ring",
                          file =>  "Marvel's Daredevil.S01E01 - Into the Ring.mp4",
                          )
                     Array(
                          episode =>  "02 - Cut Man",
                          file =>  "Marvel's Daredevil.S01E02 - Cut Man.mp4",
                          )
                  )
      Season[2] => Array
                  (
                     Array(
                          episode =>  "05 - Kinbaku",
                          file =>  "Marvel's Daredevil.S02E05 - Kinbaku.mp4",
                          )
                     Array(
                          episode =>  "06 - Regrets Only",
                          file =>  "Marvel's Daredevil.S02E06 - Regrets Only.mp4",
                          )
                  )
```

Comment: I think you'd try some code.

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far, and review [Ask]

Answer (score 1):

I was bored.  Just loop your array and use `preg_match()` to build the array using the matched groups:

```
foreach($show_arr as $val) {
    preg_match('/[^.]+\.S([\d]+)E([0-9]+[^.]+).*/', $val, $m);
    $result['Season'][(int)$m[1]][(int)$m[2]] = array('episode' => $m[2],
                                                      'file'    => $m[0]);
}
```

- `[^.]+` is 1 or more NOT dot `.` characters
- `\.S([\d]+)` is a dot `.` then `S` followed by 1 or more digits (capture as group 1)
- `E([0-9]+[^.]+)` is `E` followed by 1 or more digits followed by 1 or more NOT dot `.` characters (capture as group 2)

Additionally, this indexes the subarray by the episode.  If you don't want that, remove the `[(int)$m[2]]` and just use `[]`.